# c# check label if it contains a string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a button with to different 'actions'. 
When i first click you should see the desktop name, second click should remove this. 
But my second code shows up first moment i click, what do i do wrong?

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        lbUsername.Text = "Username: Hallo," + userName;

        if (lbUsername.Text.Contains(userName))
        {
            lbUsername.Text = "klik op de knop, dokus.";
        }
```

Comment: Because based on your code the `lbUsername.Text` always contains `userName`. So the second `lbUsername.Text` always overwrites the first one.

Comment: please explain with some examples the functionality you want to reach

Answer (score 0):

Chage it to:

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

if (lbUsername.Text.Contains(userName))
{
    lbUsername.Text = "klik op de knop, dokus.";
}
else
{
    lbUsername.Text = "Username: Hallo," + userName;
}
```

Changes applied to label's text are propagated immediately.

Comment: but now the button has only 1 click, other clicks do nothing

Comment: You have to handle clicks in your code, post the whole code you have for this button.

Comment: http://i64.tinypic.com/2h708xj.png design
http://i65.tinypic.com/v8281h.png code
i uploaded some pictures to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

Both your lblUsername.Text assignments will always execute as the if condition will always evaluate to true.

Instead try this.

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
if (lbUsername.Text.Contains(userName))
{
    lbUsername.Text = "klik op de knop, dokus.";
}
else
{
    lbUsername.Text = "Username: Hallo," + userName;
}
```

or if you are using the [Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) ?:

```
bool hasUserName = lbUsername.Text.Contains(userName))
lbUsername.Text =  hasUserName ? "klik op de knop, dokus." : "Username: Hallo," + userName;
```

Edit:

Based on the code posted on the dotnetFiddle [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lnpZoq), you should be doing this. Assign the initial value of lblUsername on Form_Load event. On Button click you can always assign the UserName text

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //THis will only be assigned when the Form is loaded.
        lbUsername.Text = "klik op de knop, dokus.";
    }

    private void btnMagic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //On Every button click this will be executed.
        string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        lbUsername.Text = "Username: Hallo," + userName;

    }
```

Comment: but when i re-click the button the text needs to be changed, but it sticks with text 1

Comment: Did you implement the code in button click event? Can you post your complete code.

Comment: yes it is in the button click event, not sure where i can post the code again? cuz it contains too much text in a comment.

Comment: You can post the complete code here(https://dotnetfiddle.net/) and share the link in your question.

Comment: nope it didn't 
I think i have to give the button an extra function or something.

Comment: WHat happens when you click the button?

Comment: When i run the program, you see a button and a label"Username". After I click it shows the username, but 2nd click won't make it dissapear